# Why does a z factor of 1 get turned into 0.999998 in my output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, 3d-analyst, volume

Just built a model that uses 3D Analyst - Surface Volume.  I am trying to use a z factor of 1.  Whenever I run the model my output table shows that a Z factor of 0.999998 was used instead of 1.  I know this is a very small difference but even so, it is skewing my results somewhat.  Really what I would like to know, is there a good explanation of why it gets changed to 0.999998 or is there a way to make it stay at 1?

---

Thanks again for your input.  When I've tried changing the type of raster, the tool grays out the z factor all together and locks it in at 0.999998. So... I'm guessing there is really no way around this using integer or floating point data.  I even tried converting to integer and using the raster calculator to multiply the data by 1000 to preserve the decimals in integer form, but was still stuck with the 0.999998 z factor. No dice.

Comment: I would say because it's a floating point, there's no such thing as 1 in float - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  This makes sense to me.  However,  just as a test I decided to run the tool on an integer raster and was still left with a Z Factor of 0.999998.  So...  Is the Z Factor itself locked in as a floating point value and not dependent on the data type of the input raster?  Thanks again, John

Comment: Yes, the Z factor is a floating point as most DEM/DSM rasters are usually 32-bit float. Try converting your int raster to a float too see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000008w000000

Comment: The number 1 can be precisely rendered in floating point, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Whuber, can you explain?  Do you know why it always changes to 0.999998?

Comment: You're correct @whuber, it's 1/3 that can't be expressed with floating point accurately. In the example given 0x3f80 0000   = 1. Perhaps it's something else internal that makes it change; I've seen this before but not thought much about it, how does it skew the result? Could you multiply the raster by 1.000002 to accommodate the shortcomings? (1 * 1.000002 * 0.999998 = 0.999999999996 which is very close to 1)

Comment: @Michael Actually, *any* number that is not an integral multiple of a small power of 2 (including negative powers) will not be exactly expressed in floating point. Perhaps the most prominent of those would be 0.1. As far as the source of the z-scale error, I can only guess. My guessing would focus on the possibility that under the hood, calculations might be performed using an *integer* representation of the elevations and at the end those are converted back. Maybe the best thing is to correct the results *after* they are produced: just multiply all volumes by 1/0.999998.

Comment: @Whuber I believe your solution of multiplying all values by 1/0.999998 would work using the raster calculator.  However, as a small update to my original post... I ended up calculating my volumes using the 3D Analyst tool - Polygon Volume.  This allowed me to calculate off of a terrain I had available which in turn allowed for me to skip the z-factor all together.

Comment: @Michael before I went with this other solution I also tried using a z-factor of 1.000002 which would magically turn back into 0.999998 during the running of the tool. So, I not sure if it was something I was doing wrong or not.  In other words, no matter what z-factor I would input the tool would change it to 0.999998 at run time.

Comment: John, I feel that it's time to contact Esri support and ask them why it always changes to 0.999998 scale factor and how to use a scale factor of 1.

Comment: have you tried running the INT tool on your data?

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with the comments, its about how you want to represent that number. If you want to store number 1 as a floating point, ArcGIS stored this number as 0,9999... It seems that this Z factor argument is stored that way. I think there's no way to store it as integer. In fact, 0,9999 is equal 1.

I must add a picture I was saw few days ago. It fits to this question.
[image]